# Keynote Error Dialogue When Opening .pptx

Tags: macos, ms-office, keynote

I opened keynote 7.3.1 on my Mac (10.12.6) and navigated to the Desktop to open a `.pptx` document.
This resulted in an error dialogue stating that it could not recognize that file format (.pptx).
What would cause this error and how could it be resolved?

Comment: Can you paste the error message verbatim?

Comment: Can you post more specific information about this issue you are having? What kind of error dialogue? What does it say? Can you post any screenshot images? Have you tried any other methods of opening the .pptx file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to locate the .pptx file in Finder (instead of the Desktop), right click on it, then move the cursor onto Open with… and select Keynote to open the Powerpoint.

If that doesn't work let us know.